# Is Clang-Tidy check "member is const qualified" too strict?

Tags: c++, clang-tidy

Clang-tidy check `cppcoreguidelines-avoid-const-or-ref-data-members` warns about `const` qualified members, referring to C++ Core Guidelines *C.12 Don’t make data members const or references in a copyable or movable type*, see

https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/cppcoreguidelines/avoid-const-or-ref-data-members.html

and

https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rc-constref

> **Enforcement** Flag a data member that is const, &, or &&
> in a type **that has any copy or move operation**.

However, it seems that said Clang-Tidy check is applied to types, that do **not** have any copy or move operation, too. Does that make sense?  I mean, `const` would implicitly make the type non-copy-assignable. But if the type is non-copyable anyway, because copy constructor and assignment operator have been deleted explicitly, should a `const` member still be avoided?

I'm asking because I noticed said warning for a non-copyable class with deleted copy constructor and assignment operator, containing some `private` `condition_variable` (which is the reason why it is non-copyable) plus some `private` `const` member set in the constructor only (being the reason for the warning).

```cpp
class Foo // simplified
{
public:
    explicit Foo(int someSetup) : someSetup{someSetup} {}
    ~Foo() = default;
    Foo(const Foo&) = delete;
    Foo(Foo&&) = delete;
    Foo& operator=(const Foo&) = delete;
    Foo& operator=(Foo&&) = delete;
    void someMethods() ...;
private:
    std::condition_variable someCondition;
    const int someSetup; // warning !!!
    int someState {};
}
```

Should I simply remove `const`? I guess the original author of the class wanted to make sure this value really doesn't change, which looks somehow comprehensible. On the other hand making it non-`const` wouldn't break anything as long as nobody else adds a public setter for this member.

Comment: There's a link in the clang-tidy check documentation that explains why they decided to make the rule stricter than core guidelines suggest. Although personally I agree that this rule is too strict.

Comment: For some reason I didn't see this link before. Thank you, that's really helpful!

Comment: "But you know a better way [than using `const` on a member variable] to tell that a private data member can’t change? *There’s no public API for changing it!*"  I concur with that position, only because `const` is insufficiently **immutable** in the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Is the check too strict?

Q: Is this check too strict, i.e., is it behaving contrary to its documented behavior?

A: **Yes**.  Quoting the [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/cppcoreguidelines/avoid-const-or-ref-data-members.html):

> This check implements [C.12](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rc-constref) from the C++ Core Guidelines.

Quoting the title of rule C.12:

> C.12: Don’t make data members const or references in a **copyable or movable type**

(emphasis mine).

Yet, it reports the example in the question, which has a `const` member in a non-copyable, non-movable class.

Of course, all of this information is already in your question.  I'm simply confirming that your interpretation is correct.

### What about the blog post link?

As noted in comments, the documentation ends with this:

> Further reading: [Data members: Never const](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2022/01/23/dont-const-all-the-things/#data-members-never-const).

The linked post argues `const` members are bad regardless of whether the type is copyable.  But whether or not you agree with that:

1. The check documentation does not anywhere say or imply it implements a different rule.  It says it implements C.12.
2. The "Further reading" language makes it sounds like the link is to supplemental material, not something that alters the meaning of the documentation that precedes it.  I'm not surprised it was overlooked before asking this question.
3. Even if you click into it, there's nothing in that blog post that suggests it was written by a `clang-tidy` developer, nor that its arguments justify making `clang-tidy` behave differently than specified in rule C.12, let alone differently than its own documentation states.  It appears to simply be advice to developers and nothing more.

Consequently, the presence of this link does not change the conclusion that either the check is misbehaving or its documentation is erroneous.

### Should I simply remove `const`?

This is rather subjective, but I would say **no**.  The `const` qualifier concisely conveys an intent for the member to not change, and that intent is helpful to a reader.

The linked blog post argues (emphasis in original):

> You might even think it was self-documenting: “this data member is `const`, so it can’t change.” But you know a better way to tell that a private data member can’t change? *There’s no public API for changing it!*

I strongly disagree.  It is far better to immediately see that something is `const` than to have to exhaustively search through all of the code that has access to it and check whether any of it changes that thing.  In fact, that's the whole point of `const`: to relieve the reader of that burden.

Another possible objection is that [`const` is not immutable](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/149555/difference-between-immutable-and-const).  Of course that's true, but that's consistent with the rest of the design of C++, which gives you useful restrictions along with the privilege to break them when necessary.  Throwing away `const` because it can be subverted is throwing away the baby with the bathwater.  No language feature is immune to poor judgment.